# Is constructing a quadtree recursively bad?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, complexity-theory

Consider the following algorithm:

---

```
Given a list POINTS of length N containing points in the interior of a square, do:

if N=0 or 1, stop
else, divide the square into 4 subsquares and repeat the above on each subsquare
```

---

Each square is represented by a node, which has associated to it two pieces of information: a list *points_contained* storing the points of POINTS contained in the square, and a list *children* pointing to other nodes; thus *children* is either empty or has 4 elements. The above algorithm thus generates a quadtree in which the external nodes (leafs) represents squares containing at most 1 point of POINTS.

The simplest method of constructing the tree is to follow the above algorithm literally and do recursion on each subsquare (once the 4 subtrees are computed, their roots become children of the original square).So the complexity would satisfy something like C(n)=4*C(n/4) thus be of complexity O(n).

A supposedly smarter method is to start with an empty square (the original square, which is the root node) and add points to it, creating subsquares as necessary:

```
for each P in POINTS, do: add_point(P,original_square)
```

where we have called the function

```
add_point(point, square):
  if square.points_contained is empty, add to it P
  is square.children is nonempty:
        find which subsquare s of square contains P then do add_point(P,s)
  if square.children empty: 
  '''*necessarily in this case square is an external node and contains exactly 1 point Q other than P*'''
      continue creating dividing into subsquares until P,Q are no longer contained in the same square
```

The second method is supposedly better than the first, but why? Is it less expensive computationally or memory wise?

Comment: What makes you think the second way is better?  To me, the first way looks like it could easily be faster because it will use fewer function calls.

Comment: Seems clear that the amount of work creating the tree is the same in both methods. The difference would seem to be that the first method spends more time moving the children around. As for the time complexity, it definitely is not O(n) in either method. In fact, I would say that the complexity is unrelated to `n`. Instead the complexity depends on the minimum distance between two points. If the distance between two points is infinitesimally small, both methods will take infinite time and infinite recursion to separate those two points.

Comment: @user3386109 : I'm talking about complexity in the average case. Assuming the points are randomly distributed about the square there are about N/4 in each subsquare do C(N)=4*C(N/4).

Comment: Why the downvote?